# What is the difference between setting the header Content-Type through Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE and usually Content-Type?

Tags: apache-camel

I can set header Content-Type so

```
<setHeader headerName="Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE">
    <constant>application/json</constant>
</setHeader>
```

and so

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <constant>application/json</constant>
</setHeader>
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? What approach can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same thing. `Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE` is a constant that refers to the string "Content-Type" and is replaced internally by Camel.